# duda consulta eloquent laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Hay alguna manera para que pueda actualizar todos los registros, en vez del primero?

$asignaru = usuarios::where('usuario_ad','=',$user->usuario_ad)->first();

Con el metodo first() no puedo actualizar el resto de campos que concuerden con el mismo nombre.

metodo https://paste.laravel.io/6ed7e5d0-9eb5-429e-b1e1-8a69bc579628

Comment: El metodo update recibe dos parametros $request y el $id todo lo que tienes que hacer es `Usuarios::findOrFail($id)->update($request->all());`

Comment: Es que no quiero actualizar todo, solo un campo, mejor dicho lo que quiero es esto.  update usuarios set asignacion='gestion' where usuario_ad='danielad';